# Correct way to implement bootstrap sidebar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Dear amazing stackoverflow peoples,

While this method works, it doesnt feel very efficient. Also, the side bar padding is quite far from the left hand margin. Is there a more proficient way to implement a sidebar?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">


      <div class="col-md-2 sidebar">

          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
            <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
            <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
            <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
            <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>



      <div class="col-md-4">

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/lambo.jpg" alt="...">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
          <p>...</p>
          <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Button</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason that I am not commenting this is that because I dont have enough reputation and if you want to fix the side bar padding then you have to include your css into the question. Otherwise we cant really tell you what the problem is.

Check out this link it is coding for a more dynamic nav bar

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sidenav_push